# Can't select a column with an odd integer

Tags: php, mysql, where-clause

I'm learning MySql for a while now and I thought it would be fun to make a fun project where you can search for a plane. The problem is that I want to select planes in PHP with the given amount of engines. This works fine for even numbers, but when using odd numbers something goes wrong, but only in the PHP code, not when I use it as a query in PHPMyadmin.

Code:

```
$result=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM civilPlanes WHERE engines=3");
//Normally 3 would be a POST variable

if (!$result) {
    die('Error: '.mysqli_error($con));
}

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 1) {
    echo '
    <tr>
        <th>Manufacturer</th>
        <th>Type</th>
        <th>Seats (max)</th>
        <th>Tumbnail</th>
        <th>Engines</th>
    </tr>';

    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo '
        <tr> 
            <td>' . $row['manufacturer'] . '</td>
            <td>' . $row['type'] . '</td> 
            <td>' . $row['maxSeats'] . '</td>
            <td>' . $row['thumbnail'] . '</td>
            <td>' . $row['engines'] . '</td>
        </tr>';
    }
}

else {
    echo 'Nothing found';
}
```

The row for the plane I'm searching for is:

```
id manufacturer      type  seats engineType  engines
21 McDonnell Douglas MD-11 410   turbofan    3
```

Every plane with another amount of engines works fine.

Oh and the script is called with AJAX.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are only returning rows if `mysqli_num_rows($result)` is GREATER than one. This means it will only work if there are *two or more* rows.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 1) {
```

You are excluding results where there is only one row. change that to:

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
```